# Push values of radio button to an array

Tags: jquery

I need something like this:

```
if (typeof data[radioname] == 'undefined' && is checked) { set data[radioname] = value; }
```

Tried this:

```
if ($(item).attr('type') == 'radio') {
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
      switch (checked) {
        case 'undefined':
          data[name] = [];
          break;
        case '0':
          data[name].push(value);
          break;
        default:
          data[name] = value;
      }

    }
```

How do I push names of radio to an array based on its checked value?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet that does what you expect.

```js
var data = {};

function pushValue($event) {
  var elem = $event.target;
  if ($(elem).attr('type') == 'radio') {
    var checked = $(elem).is(':checked');
    var name = $(elem).attr('name')
    if (checked) {
      if (!data[name]) {
        data[name] = []
      }
      data[name].push($(elem).val())
    }
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="test1" onchange="pushValue(event)"> Test
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I need something like this :    if (typeof data[radioname] == 'undefined' && is checked) { set data[radioname] = value; }

Comment: That's the exact same thing in my code above. `if(checked)` will check if the radio button is checked and `if(!data[name])` will check if its undefined or not

Answer (score 0):

Or, slightly more "compressed", you can do the following.

**Please note:** it is *not necessary* to collect the values of checked radio buttons into *arrays*, as there can only ever be *one* checked value per unique radio button name.

```js
$('input:radio').click(function(){
 var ret={};
 $('input:radio:checked').toArray()
   .forEach(r=>ret[r.name]=r.value);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ret));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="test1"> Test1
<input type="radio" name="test" value="test2"> Test2<br>
<input type="radio" name="t" value="test3"> Test3
<input type="radio" name="t" value="test4"> Test4<br>

<input type="radio" name="test" value="test5"> Test5
<input type="radio" name="test" value="test6"> Test6 &rarr; these options are linked to first group!
```